# How to get response from Base CRM API authentication

Tags: c#, api, authentication, radix

I am trying to get a response from Base API, but i keep getting "500 Internal Server Error" error. I want to get at least 401 HTTP Response which means that authentication call has failed. Here is a description of using Base API authentication:

http://dev.futuresimple.com/api/authentication

And here is my code:

```
public string Authenticate()
        {
            string result = "";
            string url = "https://sales.futuresimple.com/api/v1/";
            string email = "mail@mail.com";
            string password = "pass";
            string postData = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
            HttpWebRequest request = null;
            Uri uri = new Uri(url + "authentication.xml");
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

            using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
                writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                writeStream.Close();
            }

            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                ex = ex;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the `ContentType` to `application/xml` - this is the type of the request body. The body you're sending (`string postData = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;`) is form-encoded instead of xml. Just skipping the line `request.ContentType = "application/xml";` should do the trick. Alternatively you can encode your request body as xml.